# Issue warning on usage of specific instance

Tags: haskell, compiler-warnings

I have created an instance of a type class:

```
data Foo = Foo

instance Show Foo where
  show _ = "Foo"
```

Now this is part of a library and I want to issue a warning if a user of the library uses this instance. I have tried various things with the `WARNING` pragma but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Would you be okay with issuing a compiler error instead of warning when this instance is used? In that case, there's a solution.

Comment: @Shersh No then I could use `TypeError`... But I really want users to be able to use that instance if they want to. But it has siginificant problems.

Comment: Yes, `TypeError` can produce a compile time error. I believe there's no way to add a warning to instance usage. You probably have better luck opening a ticket to GHC; this might be a good feature request.

Comment: You can force some predefined warnings by using "questionable" code yourself (Even though this might not be a very didactic solution). If I'm not mistaken, using `show _ = _` will cause a `-Wtyped-holes` warning

Comment: @izbernardo
Yeah but that warning is hardly descriptive. I would like to say something instructive to the user. Besides that warning won't be given once the library is build. The warning is for users of the library.

Comment: It looks impossible to me. I tried to use `DEPRECATE`, but that only works on identifiers which are mentioned in the file importing the module, and we don't want to trigger the warning on `Show`, `show`, or `Foo`. Perhaps we need a type family (roughly) `TypeWarning :: String -> Type -> Type`, as a sort of type-level `trace`. Edit: [already existing ticket](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/17027)

Comment: Based on the `{-# WARNING ... #-}` syntax, `{-# WARNING (show :: Foo -> String) ... #-}` looked like the most logical candidate, but that does not work. I think it was not designed to be used with type class methods.